# How can I have a component inherit several attributes from the controller?

Tags: ember.js

New to Ember.js.

I'm trying to create robust components that will delegate to the controller for various attributes. I know that I can bind individual attributes like this, but it seems verbose.

```
{{#my-component attr1=attr1 attr2=attr2}}
  Hello
{{/my-component}}
```

It seems like it might be a common case to want to delegate everything to the controller. Is there a recommended pattern for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Your example code would be considered the correct way.

You could technically pass in a single object (possibly composed from the controller), but I would recommend against that. A component shouldn't really know much about where the data is coming from as attr1 could be a model property and attr2 could be a property of the view which doing some sort of computation. By passing in the single object you limit the flexibility of the component.

In addition to flexibility I tend to prefer the long argument list as it is clear what your component accepts; even if it is a bit more verbose. If your component is taking a huge list of arguments it may be a sign that the component is trying to do too much and you may want to break it down into smaller components.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.MyComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    attr1: function() {
        return this.get('targetObject.attr1');
    }.property('targetObject.attr1'),
    attr2: function() {
        return this.get('targetObject.attr2');
    }.property('targetObject.attr2')
});
```

From [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_targetObject):
"If the component is currently inserted into the DOM of a parent view, this property will point to the controller of the parent view."

Use with caution.